# How do I add <s> to the beginning of each sentence and </s> to the end of each sentence

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

```
pap = open('papdelete.txt', 'r')
content = pap.read()
content = content.lower()
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
SplitSentences = nlp(content)
First = nlp('<s>')
Last = nlp('</s>')
SplitSentences = [First.sents+ content +Last.sents for content in SplitSentences.sents]
```

The code above gives me a

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'generator' and 'spacy.tokens.span.Span'.
```

The contents of pap.txt:

```
"Why, my dear, you must know, Mrs. Long says that Netherfield is taken by a young man of large fortune from the north of England; that he came down on Monday in a chaise and four to see the place, and was so much delighted with it, that he agreed with Mr. Morris immediately; that he is to take possession before Michaelmas, and some of his servants are to be in the house by the end of next week."
"What is his name?"
"Bingley."
"Is he married or single?"
"Oh! Single, my dear, to be sure! A single man of large fortune; four or five thousand a year. What a fine thing for our girls!"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried an f-string (or .format)? Example:

```
f"{First}{content}{Last}"
```

instead of `First.sents+ content +Last.sents` in the last line.

Comment: I just tried it, when i try to print this, it returns a bunch of: objects <generator object at 0x0000029EBD006F70>content<generator object at 0x0000029EBD006F70>

Comment: SplitSentences = [f"{First}{content}{Last}" for content in SplitSentences.sents] worked, thank you!